# Select the last 7 days of each month

Tags: sql-server, function, date, dateadd

I am using SQL Server 2008. I'm looking to bring back only the last 7 calendar days of each month, how would I go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: sql server 2008 - I just want to bring all payments received from the last 7 days of each month since January 16

Comment: If you can specify *what the input is* (Is it e.g. just the current date, or a provided date) and what you're expecting as *output*, it would probably help a lot - if the input is just a single date (or the current date), a couple of examples that use different inputs would help a lot also .

Answer (score 0):

assuming field called logtime, get the range with

```
....where logtime BETWEEN dateadd(month,month(logtime),dateadd(year, year(logtime) - 1900,0)) - 7
                                  AND 
                                  dateadd(month,month(logtime),dateadd(year, year(logtime) - 1900,0)) - 1;
```

you also need to check that 'logtime' (replaced by your field name) is in the range of dates you are also selecting from e.g ...AND(YEAR(logtime)) = 2016 ..for example

Comment: If you have `logtime` on one side of a comparison and are using it on the other side to derive the comparison dates, you can simplify - e.g. here you need only perform a single comparison to "the day 7 days before the end of the month in which `logtime` falls".

Comment: yes you could say DAY(logtime) >= DAY(dateadd(month,month(logtime),dateadd(year, year(logtime) - 1900,0)) - 7) and also avoid any fractions of days problems

Comment: Spot on  - Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Some specific examples and direction would help. If you just want rows where, say `columnA` contains a date that falls within the last 7 days of it's respective month, then you can simply say:

```
WHERE month(columnA) != month(dateadd(day,7,columnA))
```

I.e. it asks the question, "given a date, A, does the date 7 days later fall in a different month?"

Note that neither this query nor those include in other answers is able to make use of indexes on this column (since we're using it as an input to a calculation), which is a shame.

Comment: Apologies for my lack of description, you have however cracked exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Payments P
WHERE
    P.PaymentDay < (SELECT DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(P.PaymentDay) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(P.PaymentDay), -1)) AND -- Last day of current year-month
    P.PaymentDay > (SELECT DATEADD(month, ((YEAR(P.PaymentDay) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(P.PaymentDay), -7)) -- Last 7. day of current year-month
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
--DAY(DATE) as day_of_month from day_master table.
select 
a.day_id,a.day_of_month
from day_master a LEFT JOIN (select max(day_of_month) as 'max_day_of_month',day_id,month_no,year_no from day_master group by month_no,year_no)b ON b.month_no=a.month_no and a.year_no=b.year_no
where (b.max_day_of_month-a.day_of_month)<7 and a.month_no=11 and a.year_no=2017
GROUP BY a.month_no,a.year_no,a.day_id;
```